# Multi threating Java Server

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server, communication

I am writing simple Java Server which connecting only 5 users and run simply game.
My problem is communicate with clients, because the Game object is in Main Thread and every single subthread get information about specific player move (1-5 id). I don't know how to send this information to Main Thread and update game status.

Is my code correct, there aren't exists any big mistakes (this is my first project with multitasking), and what i supposed to do to communicate with Main Thread

**Player.java**

```
package Model;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Player extends Thread{

private long id;
private Socket clientSocket;
private InputStream clientInput;
private BufferedReader clientIn;
private DataOutputStream clientOut;
private String nickname;
private boolean isReady;

public Player(long id, Socket clientSocket) throws IOException {
    this.id = id;
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    this.clientInput = this.clientSocket.getInputStream();
    this.clientIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientInput));
    this.clientOut = new DataOutputStream(this.clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    this.isReady = false;
    clientOut.writeBytes("POLACZONO\n");
    clientOut.flush();
}

public void run() {
    boolean isCorrect = false;
    try {
        while(!isCorrect) {
            String login = this.clientIn.readLine();
            if (!login.equals("") && login.startsWith("LOGIN") && login.length() > 6) {
                this.clientOut.writeBytes("OK\n");
                this.clientOut.flush();
                setNickname(login.substring(login.indexOf(" ") + 1));
                isCorrect = true;
                this.isReady = true;
            } else if (!login.equals("") && (!login.startsWith("LOGIN") || login.length() <= 6)) {
                this.clientOut.writeBytes("ERROR\n");
                this.clientOut.flush();
            }
        }

        while (true) {
            //DATA FROM CLIENT
        }
        //this.clientOut.writeBytes("START " + this.id + " " + startPlayer + "\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            this.clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Thread**

```
public void startServer(ServerSocket serverSocket) throws IOException {
        playerList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Player>());

        int remaining = 1;
        while (true) {
            if(playerList.size() < 5) {
                while (playerList.size() < 5) {
                    Socket connectionSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    playerList.add(new Player(remaining, connectionSocket));
                    playerList.get(playerList.size() - 1).start();
                    remaining++;
                }
            }

            final int startPlayer;

            if(!playerList.stream().noneMatch(x -> x.isReady())) {
                startPlayer = new Random().nextInt((5 - 1) + 1) + 1;
                for (Player player : playerList) {
                    player.getClientOut().writeBytes("START " + player.getId() + " " + startPlayer + "\n");
                }
                //GAME START
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok it means you used one thread per user for read data and just one thread to send data to users ! 
In main thread you can use a **LinkedBlockingQueue** and pass this queue to reader threads ! Each time a packet received you can put it to the queue and take it in main thread !
Soyou must write this in your reader thread :

```
queue.put(data);
```

And this in main thread :

```
data = queue.take();
```

This queue is thread safe , so it means multi thread can put and take data !
The **take** method will block thread until a data put to the queue.